# Is the space of all infinitesimal numeric sequences complete?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Is the space $c_0$ of all infinitesimal numeric sequences $a = (a_1, a_2,...,a_n,...)$ complete? The norm is $||a|| = sup|a_i|$.

As i couldn't prove that every Cauchy sequence has a limit in $c_0$ (so it'd be complete), I've been trying to find such Cauchy sequence that does not have a limit in $c_0$ to prove its incompleteness. But I haven't succeeded.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but, what is a numeric sequence?

Comment: @Don Thousand , I meant just a usual sequence of numbers (not functional or other)

Comment: But, by definition of infinitesimal sequence, every sequence converges to 0?

Comment: @ Don Thousand , sure